# Animation background size not functioning correctly in latest version of Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I stumbled across an interesting bug where animating the background size doesn't account for the transition in the latest version of Chrome. It seems to work well in Safari, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

```
background-size: 100%
transition: background-size 0.5s

  &:hover
    background-size: 150%
    transition: background-size 0.5s
```

[Here's a link to a codepen](http://codepen.io/jeffmccarthyesq/pen/XKNKrW)

Comment: Chrome 53 DEV no issue.

Answer (score -1):

**try adding a new element and then add background to that element**

add overflow:hidden to the parent element
at hover scale the child element

like

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>

.child { height:400px;width:200px;background:url....;transition:0.5s}
.parent { overflow:hidden;}
.parent:hover .child { transform:scale(1.5)}
```

**or you could use a pseudo-element like :before**

```
.parent { overflow:hidden;}
.parent:before { width:100%;height:100%;content:"";position:absolute;top:0;background:url....;transition:0.5s } 
.parent:hover:before { transform:scale(1.5)}
```

here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/z3r0ja9L/) with the second solution
the first solution works as well . you choose :)